# Copying data from one table to another table and store data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hello I am trying to execute the query for copying data from one table to another table, which is `project.purchaseorder` to `project.processingactualgrn`
the MySQL query which I tried is given below:

> Insert into project.processingactualgrn
>   (PONo,PODate,OrderingQty,ReceivedQty,BalanceQty)  Select
>   PONo,PODate,Quantity AS OrderingQty ,(Quantity-(Quantity-2) )AS
>   ReceivedQty,(Quantity-2) AS BalanceQty  from project.purchaseorder
>   where PONo=1212;

- In the above query I used values
- In the program I used placeholders using the PreparedStatement executed the query what ever the user enter the value `ex-(Quantity-2) AS BalanceQty in this '2'` has to store in database

  ```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
  RequestDispatcher rd = null;

  String pno = request.getParameter("PONo");
  int p = Integer.parseInt(pno);
  String receivedQty1 =request.getParameter("ReceivedQty1");
  int Rqty1= Integer.parseInt(receivedQty1);
  String receivedQty2 =request.getParameter("ReceivedQty2");
  int Rqty2= Integer.parseInt(receivedQty2);

  Connection conn = null;
  try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "dinga");

      PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Insert into project.processingactualgrn (PODate,PONo,OrderingQty,ReceivedQty,BalanceQty) Select PODate,PONo,Quantity AS OrderingQty,(Quantity-(Quantity-?) )AS ReceivedQty,(Quantity-?) AS BalanceQty  from project.purchaseorder where PONo=?");
      ps.setInt(1,Rqty1);
      ps.setInt(2,Rqty2);
      ps.setInt(3,p);
      System.out.println("value of ps"+ps);
      int rs = ps.executeUpdate();
      System.out.println("value of ps"+ps);
      if(rs!=0){
          rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("view/sucess.html");
          rd.forward(request, response);
      }

  } catch (SQLException e) {
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  } finally {
      try {
          if (conn != null) {
              conn.close();
          }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
      }
  }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: @user2864740,@shA.t,@mathewbutler

Comment: What is the question here?